# Tracking Source IP of Dropped Packets

Tags: centos, network-interface, packet, ifconfig

I have a server running CentOS 7 which is showing a considerable amount of `RX dropped packets` on `ifconfig`. I believe those may be caused by hardware problems such as faulty cables and connections. However, as it is a network with about 20 Windows terminals, I can't afford to check every connection to find the problematic ones. Is there any way to discover from which IP address are the dropped packets originating? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the logs. Not sure exactly which, I am thinking of dmesg, but I believe that is really for boot messages. There might also be a way to turn on logging for that...